# why did my old history and extensions appear in a fresh install of chrome?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, google-chrome, purge

I uninstalled chrome with:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

The next day I reinstalled it with:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

All the old settings from the old install appeared when I opened it up.

Comment: Do you have a google account?

Comment: Did you log in with your Google Account? Google syncs quite a lot of your settings if you let it.

Answer (score 3):

None of those commands removes any files in your `$HOME` directory.

When you `apt-get remove` apt will leave the (system) configuration files in `/etc` in place. When you `apt-get purge` apt will remove the (system) configuration files in `/etc` as well.

> ```
> remove
>        remove is identical to install except that packages are removed
>        instead of installed. Note the removing a package leaves its
>        configuration files in system. If a plus sign is appended to the
>        package name (with no intervening space), the identified package
>        will be installed instead of removed.
>
> purge
>        purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>        purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
> ```

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/apt-get.8.html for details

Neither option will remove configuration files in your home (`$HOME`) directory, those have to be removed manually.

Thus when you re-installed it reused all the files you already have.

To remove all that additional stuff run

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```